# Word or idiom for 'when someone does something according to the regulation'

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, idioms

What's the word or idiom or expression for when someone does an activity or job according to regulations of the institute or situation.

Example: He won the match {abiding by or according to the rules}

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 41, accepted):

> **Fair and square:** honestly and according to the rules.
>
> Example: She won the election fair and square.

— [Cambridge English dictionary](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/fair-and-square)

---

Or you could also say *by the book*.

> **By the book:** 
>   exactly according to rules or the law
>
> Example: The lawyers want to make sure we've done everything strictly by the book.

— [Cambridge English dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/by-the-book)

---

And single word would be *legitimately*.

> **Legitimately:** In a way that conforms to the law or to rules.
>
> Example: A legitimately elected government

— [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/legitimately)

Comment: I think "by the book" is by far the best idiomatic phrase for this.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz, that depends on the specific connotation you're trying to express.  "By the book" carries implications of lack of creativity, stuffiness, etc. -- it's the way a mid-level manager or a career bureaucrat would do things.

Comment: "Fair and square" is applicable primarily when the question is one of sportsmanship or  propriety. "By the book" is a (mostly positive) indication of closely following established procedure or rules.

Comment: @Mark I disagree that it's a negative connotation. Being creative and imaginative has its place in some fields, but most people would be happy to know that their nuclear power plants, air traffic control, etc were being done "by the book."

Comment: *No results found for "he won the match by the book".* But there's 1890 hits for "he won the match fair and square". Also, (US) *by the numbers*.

Comment: Can't upvote @chrylis-onstrike- enough -- even though OP's example has to do with sportsmanship and therefore "fair and square" makes sense in that particular case, it doesn't work in the broader context of the rest of OP's question: "when someone does an activity or job according to regulations of the institute or situation."

Comment: Agreed. Upvote @chrylis. That's the single most important sentence on this page, because at least eight people think *by the book* is the way to go. Looking at the title, now I see why, but the OP offered a sentence with a defined blank which trumps everything. And into which *by the numbers* doesn't fit either; the American version of *by the book*.

Comment: @Mazura Americans use *"by the book"* as well, but it has the connotation of basically "according to the letter of the law", which if you believe it to be a *just* law is equivalent to *"fair and square"*, but if you disagree with the law then maybe it isn't.  "*fair and square*" is definitely better in the context of sportsmanship.  "*By the book*" sounds more like a technical, but dissatisfying win in that context.

Comment: @Mark I don't think anybody would ever associate doing anything "according to the regulation(s)" with creativity. The confusion here is that "by the book" doesn't make sense when e.g. "winning". That's usually "fair and square". But nobody files their taxes "fair and square", they do that "by the book". So the question is vague but the example is specific, hence the varying answers.

Comment: Agreed that "fair and square" doesn't belong in this answer.  That phrase has only one purpose - to emphasize that a competitive victory was free of cheating, subterfuge, or interference.  It has nothing to do with the procedural or regulatory compliance conveyed with "by the book".

Comment: In the context of a match, "Fair and Square" is the best answer here.  The next closest would be "Toe the Line".

Answer (score 5):

How about **on the up-and-up**?

From M-W:

> **[up-and-up](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/up-and-up)**: an honest or respectable course -- used in the phrase *on the up-and-up*

From The Free Dictionary:

> [on the up-and-up](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/on+the+up-and-up): legitimate; open and aboveboard. *Is this deal on the up-and-up? What's the catch? Everything I do is on the up-and-up. I am totally honest.*

Your example:

> He won the match **on the up-and-up**.

Comment: This is the best fit for the specific example in the question.

Comment: The Free Dictionary marks that as ‘Primarily heard in US’.  It's not used in the UK, and would be likely to be misunderstood.  (At least, I only discovered its meaning a few years ago, and realised that for many years I'd been misunderstanding its use in a US TV series.)

Comment: I, an American, have never heard of this, and honestly if I did I would assume it's of UK origin.

Comment: The phrase is used in the UK but the meaning is completely different and irrelevant to the OP's question. It means something or some idea is gaining popularity, or "trending" to use the social media buzzword.

Answer (score 5):

That person is acting according to the **letter of the law**

> The precise wording rather than the spirit or intent. For example, Since it was the first time he'd broken the rules, the school decided to ignore the *letter of the law* and just give him a warning. [Late 1500s]

— [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/letter-of-the-law)

Answer (score 4):

**Jobsworth (noun)** informal disapproving UK:

someone who always obeys all the rules of their job even when they cause problems for other people or when the rules are silly

[Jeremy Taylor - Jobsworth](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6JOX2HfjdJ0)

Answer (score 3):

Such a person might be called a [***stickler***](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stickler) for the rules. The linked entry has it as:

> a person who thinks that a particular type of behaviour is very important, and always follows it...

Answer (score 3):

If someone adheres to the regulations strictly in order to purposefully harm the regulator, then the phrase is [malicious compliance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malicious_compliance):

> Malicious compliance (also known as malicious obedience) is the behaviour of intentionally inflicting harm by strictly following the orders of a superior while knowing that compliance with the orders will not have the intended result. The term usually implies the following of an order in such a way that ignores the order's intent but follows it to the letter. It is a form of passive-aggressive behavior.

Comment: Good illustration of the negative side of compliance. A somewhat similar term is *rules lawyering*, often used in board game communities, where a player adheres to the minutiae of the written rules, possibly ignoring the spirit of the rule, possibly to give themselves an advantage. Not exactly the same, though, since a malicious complier usually does so to irk the rule-maker, while a rules lawyer may do so to benefit themselves or irk other players. But they both represent a danger of over-adherence to the rules.

Answer (score 2):

He won the match / played **according to Hoyle**.
...

> *According to Hoyle*: In accord with the highest authority; in accord with a strict set of rules.

[[The Phrase Finder](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/according-to-hoyle.html)]

> - *This isn't a country where things are cut and dried, and done according to Hoyle.* [1902, Gilbert Parker in 'Donovan Pasha and Some
>     People of Egypt']
> - *The opening round of the Presidents' Athletic Conference men's basketball tournament went according to Hoyle.* [2007, Phil Axelrod,
>     "District Spotlight: PAC men's basketball follows form," Pittsburgh
>     Post-Gazette]

[both quotes given in the [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/according_to_Hoyle) entry]

> - *I thought everyone played according to Hoyle.* [Kid Curry]

[[Alias Smith and Jones -- The Story of Two Pretty Good Bad Men – 
*by Sandra K. Sagala, JoAnne M. Bagwell* 2015](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=TFE_DwAAQBAJ&pg=PT166&lpg=PT166&dq=%22played+according+to+Hoyle%22+-Morehead+-paperback&source=bl&ots=4XdLpCGwqy&sig=ACfU3U0Zvm5-1VHzI8FpRICVgmk7HFoVBw&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22played%20according%20to%20Hoyle%22%20-Morehead%20-paperback&f=false)]

Comment: That's an interesting phrase (and origin), and a good match for the required meaning.  But I suspect it might not be too widely understood today.

Answer (score 0):

**Within the framework**: while considering the rules.

Ex: We played within the framework of this game!

Comment: This answer needs a link to a definition. See the other answers for examples on how this is done.

Answer (score 0):

Compliant

As in within compliance standards.

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/compliant?s=t

Comment: This would be improved by including a dictionary link for your selected word and definition.

Answer (score 0):

"He won honestly." The opposite is "cheater" as discussed in [GolfDigest website](https://www.golfdigest.com/story/golf-honesty-survey)

> "Most golfers say they are honest; in 10 of our 15 situations, the majority say they never bend the rule in question."
>
> [NYTimes](https://www.nytimes.com/1996/03/20/sports/sports-of-the-times-more-than-a-drop-of-integrity.html) tells of Bobby Jones' calling a penalty on himself. When asked why, he said: "Well, you might as well have praised a man for not robbing a bank."
>
> I don't see this level of honesty in any other sport. Honesty in most other sports is dictated by referees (although it took a while to catch Lance Armstrong).
>
> The word "gracious" could never be applied to the play of that line-call disputer John McEnroe.  New technology must be credited for today's improved behavior, not nicer players.

Answer (score -2):

Here are some befitting idioms.

- [**By the book**](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/by-the-book)

> exactly according to rules or the law

- [**Above board**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/above_board)

> openly and legitimately

- [**Fair and square**](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/fair-and-square)

> honestly and according to the rules

With that, here are some relevant words.

- [**Compliance**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/compliance)

> the act or process of complying to a desire, demand, proposal, or regimen or to coercion

- [**Stickler (for sth)**](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/stickler)

> a person who thinks that a particular quality or type of behaviour is very important and expects other people to think and behave in the same way